# C++ scope to define a variable?

Tags: c++, scope, global-variables

Say I have a Class called `Tensor` and in order to fully construct an instance of the class I need to do a bunch of calculations and define auxiliary variables. In that context, I have seen code from somebody else that used a scope as such:

```
    Tensor t;
    {
        // lots of calculations to define a, b, c, ..
        t = Tensor(a, b, c, ..)
    }
```

I think I get the idea: you define the auxiliary variables in a scope because you won't need them again. I'm quite new to C++ and this is the first time encountering this. Typically I see the scope when defining a `Class` or a function. I've googled and found an example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope), under the heading "Point of declaration".

Is this good practice? When should I use it? Should I avoid it? Does it have anything to do with garbage collection?

Comment: Personally I would turn that scope into a function so you could have a syntax like `auto tensor = make_tensor(optional_arguments);`

Comment: no it has nothing to do with garbage collection, but it has everything to do with [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)

Comment: as nathan wrote, you can think of it as an inline unnamed function. Wether it is "better" to use a function or just introduce the scope is purely opinion based

Comment: Nothing in C++ has anything to do with garbage collection.

Comment: @molbdnilo Not even [\[util.dynamic.safety\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/util.dynamic.safety)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this good practice?
> When should I use it? Should I avoid it?

Reduce scope of variable is generally good, but it is generally better to initialize variable instead of set them later (so you can have `const` for example).

Creating a function or invoking a lamdba would be even better than the scope:

```
/* const */ Tensor t1 = make_tensor(/*..*/);
/* const */ Tensor t2 = []()
    {
        // lots of calculations to define a, b, c, ..
        return Tensor(a, b, c, ..);
    }(); // extra parents to call directly the lambda
// a, b, c are no longer accessible, and so cannot be misused.
```

So unless you need to expose `a`, `b` and/or `c`, or the scope is already short to not really have to worry about it (especially if there are `const`), I would reduce scope by above techniques.

> Does it have anything to do with garbage collection?

Nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this good practice?

It is not bad practice.

> When should I use it?

A common use case is with RAII-helper types. Consider the example presented on cppreference for [scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) (comments added by me):

> ```
> void assign_lunch_partner(Employee &e1, Employee &e2)
> {
>     static std::mutex io_mutex;
>     {
>         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(io_mutex);
>         std::cout << e1.id << " and " << e2.id << " are waiting for locks" << std::endl;
>     }   // <--
>  
>     {
>     // [...]
> ```

The lock `lk` automatically releases the mutex when it goes out of scope. This couple of lines is probably not worth the effort to put them inside a dedicated function, so the author just opened a scope such that the lock only holds the mutex till `} // <--`.

> Should I avoid it?

This whole idea of not introducing a function, but just a scope is no longer maintanable when the size of the code is more than just a couple of lines. Though this is purely opinion-based and a matter of style.

> Does it have anything to do with garbage collection?

No. It has nothing to do with garbage collection. As illustrated above, it has something to do with [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

Comment: i slightly misunderstood the question. Completely ignored the thingy about initializing `t`